# How to call mfc C++ function in HTML JavaScript and how to call JavaScript Function in mfc C++?

Tags: javascript, html, c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I search on internet 1 week regularly no solution. I found one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2352/JavaScript-call-from-C.
But that solution is very difficult to understand.

This program can call JavaScript but online. I just want to call JavaScript Internally. For example test.htm inside the project. Just 1 simple function of JavaScript and 1 simple function of c++. Please Help.

According to my project any simple function. For example adding from JavaScript or multiplication from c++ etc.

Comment: Why exactly are you wanting to use Javascript from MFC / vice versa? That seems like an odd requirement to have.

Comment: Because this is my project.

Comment: @MuhammadRaza, I think the question meant "what is your project trying to do by calling Javascript APIs from C++ (what is the functionality?)

Comment: To call javascript API from C++, you will need to embed (and launch) a [javascript engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine) in your application, similar to what a browser does. To call a C++ API from Javascript, you will have to wrap it in an internal javascript API and expose it to the javascript runtime. Both are very wide subjects and the way you do this, should depend on what javascript engine you end up choosing.

Comment: Sir, i edit some lines in my question. Now the question is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way to call javascript function from MFC application
Suppose this is a javascript function in your html file.
**JAVSCRIPT function**

There may be different type of javascript function
**Type 1:** No arguments, No return Value

```
function myfunction()
{
    Alert('Hey I am Here');
}
```

**Type 2:** having  Arguments with No return Value

```
function myfunction1(value)
{
    Alert(value);
}
```

**Type 3:** Arguments may or may not have with return Value

```
function myfunction2(value)
{
    return value;
}
```

---

This function is used to call javascript function

```
BOOL CMyDlg::CallClientScript(LPCTSTR pStrFuncName, CStringArray* pArrFuncArgs, CComVariant* pOutVarRes)
{
BOOL bRes = FALSE;
CComVariant vaResult;
CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> pIDoc2;
if(SUCCEEDED(this->GetDHtmlDocument(&pIDoc2)))  //Uses CDHtmlDialog as 'this'
{
    //Getting IDispatch for Java Script objects
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spScript;
    if(SUCCEEDED(pIDoc2->get_Script(&spScript)))
    {
        //Find dispid for given function in the object
        CComBSTR bstrMember(pStrFuncName);
        DISPID dispid = NULL;
        if(SUCCEEDED(spScript->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &bstrMember, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &dispid)))
        {
            const int arraySize = pArrFuncArgs ? pArrFuncArgs->GetSize() : 0;

            //Putting parameters  
            DISPPARAMS dispparams;
            memset(&dispparams, 0, sizeof dispparams);
            dispparams.cArgs      = arraySize;
            dispparams.rgvarg     = new VARIANT[dispparams.cArgs];
            dispparams.cNamedArgs = 0;

            for( int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            {
                CComBSTR bstr = pArrFuncArgs->GetAt(arraySize - 1 - i); // back reading
                bstr.CopyTo(&dispparams.rgvarg[i].bstrVal);
                dispparams.rgvarg[i].vt = VT_BSTR;
            }

            EXCEPINFO excepInfo;
            memset(&excepInfo, 0, sizeof excepInfo);
            UINT nArgErr = (UINT)-1;  // initialize to invalid arg

            //Call JavaScript function         
            if(SUCCEEDED(spScript->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, 0, DISPATCH_METHOD, &dispparams, &vaResult, &excepInfo, &nArgErr)))
            {
                //Done!
                bRes = TRUE;
            }
            //Free mem
            delete [] dispparams.rgvarg;
        }
    }
}

if(pOutVarRes)
    *pOutVarRes = vaResult;

return bRes;
}
```

**How to use?**
On click of any button you can call this function, for example

```
onbuttonclickOk()
{
    CStringArray arrArgs;
    CComVariant varRes;
    //arrArgs.Add(_T("1"));//you can add value to CStringArray 
    //arrArgs.Add(_T("2"));//if your javascript function having any arguments
    CallClientScript(L"myfunction",&arrArgs,&varRes);
}
```

**How to get return value of javaScript function?**
If your javascript function is returning any value, it will be stored in`varRes` variable.
you can get return value like

```
CString strTmp;
if(CallClientScript(L"myfunction3",&arrArgs,&varRes))
{
    if(varRes.vt == VT_BSTR){
        strTmp = varRes.bstrVal;// return value of javascript function.
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
**Work with edit control**
suppose you have an edit control like this

```
<input type="text" id="MyEdit" />
```

In DoDataExchange add one line

```
void CMyDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDHtmlDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_DHtml_ElementInnerText(pDX, _T("MyEdit"), m_strMyEdit);// add this line
}
```

`m_strMyEdit` is a `CString` variable you can declare in your `.h` file.
OnInitDialog, you can give any value to show in edit control, like:

```
m_strMyEdit = _T("Enter anything");
```

And if you want to update editbox value later in your program just add these lines

```
UpdateData();
m_strMyEdit =_T("Hello World");// give new value
UpdateData(FALSE);
```

if you want to access editbox value you can directly use `m_strMyEdit` variable.
I think this will help you..!!!

Comment: Thank you himanshu this code is work. But if i want to call a c++ function in java script or in another word. Call .ccp function in .htm. How i do that?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to call `c++` in `JavaScript` but you can call c++ function on click of HTML elements like, div, span, anchor.. etc.

Comment: Error 12 error C3861: 'DDX_DHtml_ElementText': identifier not found c:\users\administrator\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\mfcapplication7\mfcapplication7\mfcapplication7dlg.cpp 45 1 MFCApplication7

Comment: I am using html dialog.

Comment: check in `stdafx.h` file , have you added `#include <afxdhtml.h>`?

Comment: I want to display 'Hey I am Here' in text box. Using MyEdit in .cpp.

Comment: yes file is included.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79286/discussion-between-muhammad-raza-and-himanshu).